# Firefox <input> acting shady

Tags: html, css, firefox

```
<div class="intend"><input class="Name" placeholder="Name"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Surname" placeholder="Surname"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Company" placeholder="Company"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Position" placeholder="Position"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Street" placeholder="Street"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Street2" placeholder="Street2"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Zip" placeholder="Zip"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="City" placeholder="City"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Country" placeholder="Country"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Tel" placeholder="Tel"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Fax" placeholder="Fax"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Email" placeholder="Email"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="ArtistName" placeholder="ArtistName"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Web" placeholder="Web"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Skype" placeholder="Skype"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Twitter" placeholder="Twitter"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Instagram" placeholder="Instagram"></div>
<div class="intend"><input class="Facebook" placeholder="Facebook"></div>
```

I tried to replicate the issue in

## JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/LLwz4s2q/2/

but to no avail.

When you go to https://liebdich.biz and scroll down to "Email" ( or use the navigation ) you find blocks of inputs below the login. When you mouseover, you have a highlighting effect. But the same with the inspector, it is acting shady.

You have a hot area on top of the input and a hot area below the middle of the input.

What is this?

Comment: Your HTML could use some `type="text"`s

Comment: @DJDavid98 Trying (y).

Comment: @DJDavid98: `type` attribute is optional, and implicitly defaults to `text` anyway if it is absent.

Comment: @DJDavid98 To no avail.

Comment: Btw, the login `<input>` is working properly?!

Comment: You should go validate your HTML first, it is a mess: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://liebdich.biz/

Comment: @CBroe Improved. Can not `alt` the images for the rest of the 110 errors. And an implemented shop. HTML not mine. Arrgh.

Comment: Missing `alt` attribute should not be relevant for this issue – but some of the nesting errors/wrongfully closed/placed tags might. Is the issue gone now?

Comment: @CBroe The nesting errors are in the last element "Basic". It is a mess `HTML` that I pulled from the shop. I am working on it, but this is not the issue here, I guess.

Comment: @CBroe Can you look into `height`/`line-height`. Something is moving there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a

## CSS

```
top: 59px;
```

issue.

I put a spacer `<div>` in between the login and the `<input>`s and it is working.

https://liebdich.biz

Comment: Never use spacer divs. That's a hack at best and doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @Rob What else could I do? Bummer that I can not replicate the issue in JSFIDDLE. :( And everything is working now. So, what is actually so bad on a spacer div?